# How to measure First Paint (FP)?

Tags: web, google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed Insights and Lighthouse are able to measure First Contentful Paint (FCP), First Meaningful Paint (FMP) and other metrics, but how I can measure First Paint (FP)?

Comment: performance.getEntriesByType('paint') ? It's also shown in the Performance panel.

Comment: Wondering what are you referring by "FB"? What i understand First Paint is FP not FB.

Comment: @SamarPanda you are right, it is FP not FB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can measure First Paint (FB) the same way as Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) in Chrome DevTools -> Performance.

You can check more info in Chrome DevTools [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/09/devtools#LCP).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can measure First-Paint(FP) by below two methods of performance API.

1. Using `getEntriesByType` - Code snippet below:

   const {name, startTime} = performance.getEntriesByType('paint')[0];
   console.log(`Metric Name: ${name}, StartTime: ${startTime}`);

[image]

2. Using `getEntriesByName` - Code snippet below:

   const {name, startTime} = performance.getEntriesByName('first-paint')[0];
   console.log(`Metric Name: ${name}, StartTime: ${startTime}`);

[image]